# SQL HOW TO DELETE ONLY BLANK SPACE IN THE BEGINING OF A CELL

Tags: sql

i HAVE A COLUMN WITH 2000 ROWS AND SOME OF THEM BLANK SPACE IN THE beginning
FOR EXAMPLE:
  T R
How can i make all cells to clear blank space in the beginning ?

Comment: Have you tried `TRIM()`?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE SET YOUR_COLUMN = LTRIM(YOUR_COLUMN);
```